# Select multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

This is a part of my DB structure that I want to query:

[image: DB structure]

The relations are these:

- article.art_author - user.usr_id
- article.art_id - tag_article.rel_art_id
- tag_article.rel_tag_id - tag.tag_id

I want to select the articles that are written from selected users (by usr_id) OR the article that have the selected tags (by tag_id) in one query if possible.

I have tried this but does not give me the desired result:

```
SELECT * FROM 
                ((article JOIN user on article.art_author = user.usr_id)
                JOIN
                tag_article on article.art_id = tag_article.rel_art_id)
                JOIN
                tag on tag_article.rel_tag_id = tag.tag_id
                WHERE
                article.art_lang = '$cur_lang'
                $sql_in
                ORDER BY
                article.art_date desc
                LIMIT $first_record, $range
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct a.art_id
from article a,
    user u,
    tag_article ta,
    tag t
where a.art_author=u.user_id
    and ta.rel_art_id = a.art_id
    and ta.rel_tag_id = t.tag_id
    and (u.usr_id in (<your selected users>) or t.tag_id in (<your selected tag>))
```

I wrote all joints so you can select all columns you want, but it can be done more rapidly if you just need article data :

```
select a.art_id
    from article a,
    tag_article ta
where a.art_id=ta.rel_art_id
    and (a.art_author in (<your selected users>) or ta.rel_tag_id in (<your selected tags>))
```

Comment: Thank but it's not working! Even if I use SELECT DISTINCT gives me an article twice..

Comment: Yes that's what's happening. Thank again for your time!

Comment: What can I do to get an article that has more than one tags linked to it, only one time?

Comment: You'll have to avoid displaying fields from tags or tags_article table, or using [GROUP_CONCAT](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,287931) and GROUP BY commands.